# Generate multiple forms on button click - PHP/Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm working on a project.I have a form in which user can upload files.I want to make a php function that can allow user to upload more files if he wants.

In other words,i need a technique with which i can display the form multiple times below one another.

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" >
<input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
<input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
```

Instead of repeatedly copy pasting the same form,i want that user itself generate the form according to his no of files,he want to upload!

In order words,i need script (PHP or JAVASCRIPT) that that generate above lines of codes when a button is clicked.

Example:if a user want to upload 3 files,he will click button three times and three upload file fields will show as shown in image.
[image]

Thanks for the help.I really appreciate it !

Comment: sorry .I missed </form> tag at the end :)

Comment: If you missed it, please edit the post and add it in there, not in a comment. Also, you should include code examples of your attempts.

Comment: And... what have you tried? SO is not a "write some code for me" kind of place. We help answer question on problems you are having **with code you wrote**

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you do it:

```js
function generateForm() {

  var f = document.createElement("form");
  f.setAttribute('method', "post");
  f.setAttribute('action', "action.php");

  var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
  i.setAttribute('type', "file");
  i.setAttribute('name', "fileToUpload");
  i.setAttribute('id', "fileToUpload");

  var s = document.createElement("input");

  s.setAttribute('type', "submit");
  s.setAttribute('value', "Upload");
  s.setAttribute('name', "submit");

  f.appendChild(i);
  f.appendChild(s);

  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);

}

generateForm();
```

```html
<button onclick="generateForm()">Add more files</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is one form containing multiple file upload fields.

First, let's create a function which will add another form.

You can use `document.createElement`, a JavaScript function, to create new DOM elements such as `<input>` and `<form>`.

You can use `.appendChild`, a method of HTML DOM objects, to add the method's argument to the element it's called on. (For example, `a.appendChild(b)` appends `b` into `a`.

Using this, we can create a function which

- Makes a form
- Makes an input
- Adds the input to the form
- Adds the form to the body

Hence, our resulting code is below

```js
function addInputToForm() {
  const form = document.createElement("FORM")
  const input = document.createElement("INPUT")
  const submit = document.createElement("INPUT")
  
  form.appendChild(input)
  form.appendChild(submit)
  
  document.body.appendChild(form)
  
  input.type = "file"
  submit.type = "submit"
  
  submit.value = "Upload File"
}
```

```html
<button onclick="addInputToForm()">Add upload field</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
<form action="action.php" method="post" >
    <input type="button" value="Add more files" id="addFileFieldBtn"  />
    <div class="fileUploadField"><input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" /></div>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>

<script>
$(document).on("click", "#addFileFieldBtn", function(){
    var fileFields = $('.fileUploadField');
    fileFields.last().after('<div class="fileUploadField">'+fileFields.first().html()+'</div>');
});
</script>
```

You will get an array of files on Server side.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `button` under your form with a plus in it:
`<button onClick="addform()">+</button>`

and add js to add a new form:

```
<script>
    function addform(){
        code = "<form action="action.php" method="post" ><input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload"><input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit"></form>
        newForm = document.createElement('form');
        newForm.innerHTML = code;
        document.getElementByID('formContainer').appendChild(newForm)
   }
</script>
```